# How to observe my object is dirty

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a class with few properties. (a model)
At the component the object of the class can be manipulated.
At a certain moment I need to check if any object property has been changed.
How can I do it?

I would like to observe on on place, not at every property at the form (onChange)="...".

I don't work with -Element, so I can't use ([ngModel])="..." (onChange)="...".

The object will be filled at the runtime. So I can not do a copy (clone) at onInit().

Than there is the ChangeDetectorRef-class. But I can not find out how to chack there are changes or not.

Would be great to get some help!
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for similar situation using FormGroup module; refer [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) for FormGroup section once.

Comment: I'm working with DevExtreme -controls. So it will be quit difficult / impossible to use Angular FormGroup on it. :(

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
I found the possibility to catch up when the object is set with all there values and I set up a clone. on the end I do compare the object and them's clone.

Using library **Lodash** and methods **cloneDeep**(myObject) and **isEqual**(myObject, myObjectsClone).

Frank